# binary tree with CLIPS

Tags: structure, binary-tree, clips

In clips I have the  try implement a binary tree structure, i know how implement binary tree in other language but i can't  representation my Knowledge .

I am beginner in CLIPS. 
my try:

```html
(deftemplate root
    (slot lchild)
    (slot rchild)
    (slot data))

(deftemplate node
    (slot lchild)
    (slot rchild)
    (slot data)
)
 ;------------------------------------------
(deffacts initial-facts
(emptyyy)
(root (lchild niil) (rchild niil) (data niil))
 )
;-----first insert
(defrule  insert-root-1
(initial-fact)
?emp <-(emptyyy)
?ro <-(root (lchild ?lr)(rchild ?rr)(data ?dr))
=>
(retract ?emp )
(assert (notemptyyy))
(printout t "enter your data:  "  )
(bind ?r  (read))
(modify ?ro (lchild niil)(rchild niil)(data ?r))
(printout t "---->root = " ?r  "----> leftchild= " ?lr    "--->  rightchild= " ?rr crlf)
)
;................
(defrule insert-node
(notemptyyy)
?ro <-(root (lchild ?lr)(rchild ?rr)(data ?dr))
=>
(printout t "enter your node data:  "  )
(bind ?dn  (read))
(if(<= ?dr  ?dn ) 
then
(modify ?ro (lchild ?lr)(rchild ?dn)(data ?dr))
(printout t "---->node = " ?dr  "----> leftchild= " ?lr    "--->  rightchild= " ?dn crlf)
else
(modify ?ro (lchild ?dn)(rchild ?rr)(data ?dr))
(printout t "---->node = " ?dr  "----> leftchild= " ?dn    "--->  rightchild= " ?rr crlf)
)
)
```

i dont know how continue,this code just work for root node!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as you would do in a procedural language, you have to traverse the tree to determine where to insert new nodes. You'll need to use facts to keep track of where you are in the tree traversal.

```
(defglobal ?*next-id* = 0)

(deffunction next-id()
   (bind ?*next-id* (+ ?*next-id* 1)))

(deftemplate node
   (slot id)
   (slot parent (default none))
   (slot left-child (default none))
   (slot right-child (default none))
   (slot data))

(deftemplate process
   (slot data))

(deftemplate traverse
   (slot id))

(defrule get-data
   (not (process))
   =>
   (printout t "Enter data: ")
   (assert (process (data (read)))))

(defrule root-node
   ?f <- (process (data ?value))
   (test (numberp ?value))
   (not (node))
   =>
   (retract ?f)
   (assert (node (id 0) 
                 (data ?value))))

(defrule already-exists
   ?f <- (process (data ?value))
   (test (numberp ?value))
   (node (data ?value))
   =>
   (retract ?f)
   (printout t "Node already exists" crlf))

(defrule start-traverse
   (process (data ?value))
   (test (numberp ?value))
   (not (node (data ?value)))
   (node (id 0))
   =>
   (assert (traverse (id 0))))

(defrule add-left
   ?p <- (process (data ?value))
   ?t <- (traverse (id ?id))
   ?n <- (node (id ?id) (data ?ovalue) (left-child none))
   (test (< ?value ?ovalue))
   =>
   (retract ?p ?t)
   (bind ?nid (next-id))
   (modify ?n (left-child ?nid))     
   (assert (node (id ?nid) (data ?value) (parent ?id))))

(defrule add-right
   ?p <- (process (data ?value))
   ?t <- (traverse (id ?id))
   ?n <- (node (id ?id) (data ?ovalue) (right-child none))
   (test (> ?value ?ovalue))
   =>
   (retract ?p ?t)
   (bind ?nid (next-id))
   (modify ?n (right-child ?nid))     
   (assert (node (id ?nid) (data ?value) (parent ?id))))

(defrule traverse-left
   (process (data ?value))
   ?t <- (traverse (id ?id))
   (node (id ?id) (data ?ovalue) (left-child ?left&~none))
   (test (< ?value ?ovalue))
   =>
   (modify ?t (id ?left)))

(defrule traverse-right
   (process (data ?value))
   ?t <- (traverse (id ?id))
   (node (id ?id) (data ?ovalue) (right-child ?right&~none))
   (test (> ?value ?ovalue))
   =>
   (modify ?t (id ?right)))
```

Comment: I sincerely thank for your attention and solutions
Is it possible to change the program that:
The goal is  implement structural, by using facts and  
knowledge of the data structure stored and presented 
the following rules
Parents(node): to find the father of a node
Rightchild(node): to find of the right child node
Childleft(node): to find of the left child node
leaves:to find All leaves binary tree 
and show in output

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to your code:

```html
(defrule r-child
?t<- (rchild-node ?value)
  (node (id ?id) (data ?value) (right-child ?r))
  (node (id ?r) (data ?ovalue) )
=>
(retract ?t)
(printout t "right child node<--- " ?value " --> is:= " ?ovalue crlf ) 
)


(defrule l-child
?t<- (lchild-node ?value)
  (node (id ?id) (data ?value) (left-child ?l))
  (node (id ?l) (data ?ovalue) )
=>
(retract ?t)
(printout t "left child node<--- " ?value " --> is:= " ?ovalue crlf ) 
)

(defrule leave
  ?t<- (leaf)
  (node (id ?id) (data ?value) (left-child none) (right-child none) )
 =>
(printout t "-leaf- " ?value  crlf ) 
)

(defrule parent
?t<- (parent-node ?value)
(node (id ?id) (data ?value)(parent ?p  ))
(node (id ?p) (data ?ovalue) )
=>
(retract ?t)
(printout t "parent<--- " ?value " --> is:= " ?ovalue crlf ) 
)
```